# multiple checkbox div 100% height of body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem to fix height of div that have multiple checkboxes inside, so the height dont be more then 100% of window (body). I try so many staff so im out of solutions. If someone know some tricks to help me with this one, i will be so much pleased

```js
$(".open").on("click", function () {
    $("#multiselect-wrap").animate({
        left: 0
    });
    $(".open").hide();
    $(".close").show();
});

$(".close").on("click", function () {
    $("#multiselect-wrap").animate({
        left: -220
    });
    $(".open").show();
    $(".close").hide();
});
```

```css
#multiselect-wrap {
 background-color: #f6f6f6;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 0 8px 10px 10px;
 border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
}
.multiselect {
 width: 200px;
 height: 100%;
 overflow:auto;
 border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.multiselect label {
 display:block;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 4px 10px;
}
.multiselect input {
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.multiselect p {
 padding-left: 5px;
}
.open, .close {
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -81px;
 width: 100px;
 top: 40px;
 background-color: #f6f6f6;
 border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
 border-top-color: #f6f6f6;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiselect-wrap">
    <p>Select Criteria(s)</p>
    <div class="open">Show Options</div>
    <div class="close">Hide Options</div>
    <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="content">
            <label>Green
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />
            </label>
            <p>Heading</p>
            <label>Green
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />
            </label>
            <label>Red
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" />
            </label>
            <label>Blue
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3" />
            </label>
            <label>Orange
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4" />
            </label>
            <label>Purple
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5" />
            </label>
            <label>Black
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="6" />
            </label>
            <label>White
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7" />
            </label>
            <label>Black
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="8" />
            </label>
            <label>White
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="9" />
            </label>
            <p>Heading</p>
            <label>Green
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />
            </label>
            <label>Red
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" />
            </label>
            <label>Blue
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3" />
            </label>
            <label>Orange
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4" />
            </label>
            <label>Purple
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5" />
            </label>
            <label>Black
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="6" />
            </label>
            <label>White
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7" />
            </label>
            <label>Black
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="8" />
            </label>
            <label>White
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="9" />
            </label>
            <p>Heading</p>
            <label>Green
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />
            </label>
            <label>Red
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" />
            </label>
            <label>Blue
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3" />
            </label>
            <label>Orange
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4" />
            </label>
            <label>Purple
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5" />
            </label>
            <label>Black
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="6" />
            </label>
            <label>White
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7" />
            </label>
            <label>Black
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="8" />
            </label>
            <label>White
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="9" />
            </label>
            <p>Heading</p>
            <label>Green
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />
            </label>
            <label>Red
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" />
            </label>
            <label>Blue
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3" />
            </label>
            <label>Orange
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4" />
            </label>
            <label>Purple
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5" />
            </label>
            <label>Black
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="6" />
            </label>
            <label>White
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7" />
            </label>
            <label>Black
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="8" />
            </label>
            <label>White
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="9" />
            </label>
            <p>Heading</p>
            <label>Green
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />
            </label>
            <label>Red
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" />
            </label>
            <label>Blue
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3" />
            </label>
            <label>Orange
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4" />
            </label>
            <label>Purple
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5" />
            </label>
            <label>Black
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="6" />
            </label>
            <label>White
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7" />
            </label>
            <label>Black
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="8" />
            </label>
            <label>White
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="9" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to me you have to subtract the height of above p tag("

Select Criteria(s)

") from the height of div that have multiple checkboxes inside. You can achieve this by jquery. I have done small modification in code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nsjquery/jat7rq5w/)

```js
$(".open").on( "click", function() {
    $("#multiselect-wrap").animate({left:0});
    $(".open").hide();
    $(".close").show();
});
$(".close").on( "click", function() {
    $("#multiselect-wrap").animate({left: -220});
    $(".open").show();
    $(".close").hide();
});
var getMultiSelectHeight = $(".multiselect").height();
$(".multiselect").height(getMultiSelectHeight-($(".selectText").outerHeight(true)+20))
```

Comment: When i import html and css in my project i made some modification so instead $(".multiselect").height(getMultiSelectHeight-($(".selectText").outerHeight(true)+20)) i add like this $("#multiselect-wrap").height(getMultiSelectHeight-($(".selectText").outerHeight(true)+10)) Reason why i do this is because css is not same like i post here.Thank you for quick answer

Answer (score 2):

There is one solution with CSS. See demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrayeuet/2/).

I add below for setting the default html viewport margin 0:

```
html, body{
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and updated `.multiselect` with CSS3 to calculate the height:

```
height: calc(100% - 50px); // 50px is <p>'s height including margin
```

Try to resize the screen in the demo, you will see the height will change dynamically.